# How to get the windows native look in Java GUI programming?

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface

I am new to Java programming and want to whether it is possible to get the windows native look in Java GUI applications. Obviously Swing won't work.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use the following:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Read [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) and [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more information.

Comment: if you use this you have to do the update as you can see in Kumar answer below:
`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frmae);`
`updateComponentTreeUI(frame);`

Comment: @Csanesz if you change the L&F after the application start up when the UI is already visible then `updateComponentTreeUI` is required, otherwise it is not needed. The mentioned tutorial discusses various options.

Comment: Don't forget to surround it with try/catch (checked exceptions)

Answer (score 16):

Try this....

The syntax is:

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(PLAF);   (Pluggable Look and Feel)`

So, **you must include the below 3 lines.**

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

**SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame)** is used for refreshing the frame after the change.

Comment: a) not recommended to hard-code class names b) no need for the third of the three lines (it's already handled in the second :-)

Comment: Only the first line is necessary, if you run it before realizing any GUI components.

Answer (score -4):

try this code:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("Windows")
```

Comment: -1 wrong - you would at least need the fully qualified classname of the LAF

Comment: @RonE dooh, nearly fainted and quickly tried (which you might have done as well ;-) It's throwing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Windows` just as documented, so curious: why do you think that?

Comment: @kleopatra My mistake, I'm just so used to a helper method that makes use of parameter `lookAndFeelString` to select the L&F.    `for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if (lookAndFeelString.equals(info.getName())) { UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());}}` I'll remove my other comment to not be misleading.