# Is there a way to make generic-looking buttons in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the windows native look in Java GUI programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425103/how-to-get-the-windows-native-look-in-java-gui-programming)

Is it possible to make a Java button that looks like the default system scheme? For example, something that looks like this?

[image]

Comment: Default system scheme? You mean the Operating System?

Comment: Have you taken a look at either Swing or AWT? They both provide ways to accomplish such a task.

Comment: Take a loot at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425103/how-to-get-the-windows-native-look-in-java-gui-programming

Comment: the school teachers care about this stuff? Not that important :P